# Proof of inequality $\frac{2-a}{2+a}<e^{-a}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

How can I prove that

$$\frac{2-a}{2+a}<e^{-a}$$

for all $a \geq 0$ ?

For $a \geq 2$ it is clear, but how can it be shown for $0<a<2$ ?

Comment: For $a=-2$ it is wrong.

Comment: Some times this type of problem can be solved by examining the behavior of a function $f(a)=\frac{2-a}{2+a}-e^{-a}$. As you can see, $f(0)=0$. Then, find the derivative of $f$ to see if it a maximum. If it is, then $f(a)<0$ everywhere else, which proves the initial statement.

Comment: For $a\le 0$ it is wrong. Are you asking about $0<a<2$?

Comment: Do you guys mean for $2<a \le 0$? Because for $a<-2$ the left hand side is negative, therefore it's not wrong

Comment: sorry, $a \geq 0$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2-a}{2+a}\lt e^{-a}\tag1$$
We know that $(1)$ holds for $a\lt -2\ \text{or}\ a\ge 2$ trivially.

So, let us consider the case when $0\lt a\lt 2$ (Note that $(1)$ does not hold for $a=0$).

Since
$$(1)\iff f(a)=a+2+(a+2)e^a-4e^a\gt 0,$$
we have
$$f'(a)=e^a(a-1)+1,\ \ f''(a)=ae^a\gt 0.$$
Since $f'(a)$ is increasing with $f'(0)=0$, we know that $f'(a)\gt 0$ for $0\lt a\lt 2$. Since $f(a)$ is increasing for $0\lt a\lt 2$, we have $f(a)\gt f(0)=2+2-4=0$ for $0\lt a\lt 2$. **Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = e^{-x}(2+x)$.

$$
f'(x) = -e^{-x}(1+x)
\\
f''(x) = xe^{-x} > 0
$$
hence $f$ is convex on the domain $\{x:x>0\}$.

The linear approximation around $0$ of $f$ is:
$$
g(x) = f(0) + f'(0) x = 2 - x
$$hence
$$x>0\implies 
f(x) > g(x)
\\
\implies e^{-x} > \frac{2-x}{2+x}
$$

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: +1 What exactly is wrong with this solution. Why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(a)=\frac{2-a}{2+a}-e^{-a}$$
Now $f'(a)=e^{-a}-\frac4{(a+2)^2}$
$f'(a)<0\;\forall\; a\ge0$ and also $f(0)=f'(0)=0$
You can do that probably by differentiating further.

Comment: At first glance showing that $f'(a) < 0$ on, say, $(0, 2)$, doesn't appear to be any easier than showing that $f(a) < 0$ on the interval, as in both cases one is comparing an exponential with a rational function.

Comment: @Travis #agree ${}$

Answer (score -2):

The inequality is false for $a\in[-2,0]$, as you can easily check. I have included both endpoints because the lhs is undefined at $-2$ and they are equal at $0$.

To prove it for $a>0$ the easiest way is just to use the series, lhs is $1-a+\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^4}{4}+\frac{a^4}{8}+\dots$, but rhs is $1-a+\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^4}{6}+\frac{a^{24}}{8}+\dots$

A trivial induction on the coefficients establishes the result.

[Added later] The question has now been changed to require $a\ge 0$. The result remains false at $a=0$.

[Added still later] Of course, more elementary approaches are possible, like mathlove's solution. But the question is tagged calculus, so presumably one is allowed to use it.]

Comment: what's with your every second editing?